# Ошиба при сборке на FlashDevelop Standard library not found

Tags: haxe

При сборке в программе FlashDevelop проекта OpenFL в консоли выдает строки ошибки:

*Standard library not found*

*Build halted with errors.*

Сам код проекта просто должен выводить строку "Hello!".

Посмотрел в папке lib и так же нашел папки openfl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил путем переустановки Haxe. Бывает же ...